# Scala Play framework URL in iframe is not working

Tags: java, scala, iframe, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to display this `iframe` in my scala play view;

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:9020/index.html#/group/sectiona/sectionb">Loading...</iframe>
```

If I hard code this url, it works. But I want it to be dynamic. I tried;

1. `<iframe src="http://localhost:9020/index.html#/group/{{ 'http:\//localhost:9020\/#\/group\/' + myclass.section + '\/' + myclassb.section }}/testtopic">Loading...</iframe>`
2. `<iframe src="http://localhost:9020/index.html#/group/{{myclass.section}}/sectionb">Loading...</iframe>`
3. `<iframe class="graphiframe" src="{{ 'http:\//hello' + myclass.section + 'world'}}" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden" height="100%" width="100%">Loading...</iframe>`
4. `<iframe class="graphiframe" src="{{ 'http://hello' + myclass.section + 'world'}}" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden" height="100%" width="100%">Loading...</iframe>`

etc..

None of this works. in 4 and 5, when I inspected the element, the entire src is gone from iframe, and I got an iframe with error messages `Action not found. For request 'GET /%7B%7B%20'http:///hello'%20+%20myclass.section%20+%20'world'%7D%7D'` and `Action not found. For request 'GET /%7B%7B%20'http://hello'%20+%20myclass.section%20+%20'world'%7D%7D'` respectively. I have made changes in application.conf like `play.filters.headers.frameOptions = null`. It use Play 2.4.0.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need "the magic ‘@’ character": https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaTemplates

so

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:9020/index.html#/group/{{myclass.section}}/sectionb">Loading...</iframe>
```

must be

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:9020/index.html#/group/@myclass.section/sectionb">Loading...</iframe>
```

or

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:9020/index.html#/group/@{myclass.section}/sectionb">Loading...</iframe>
```

Comment: tried both. It shows `localahost:9020/#/group/@{@myclass.section}` and in first case `localahost:9020/#/group/@@myclass.section`. If i use `{{ }}` instead of `{ }`, then nothing works.